# php language redirect automatically

Tags: php, if-statement, redirect

Good day,

My web site has EN, RU, AZ language. how can I make a script to change the language automatically with locations?
This script works:

```
  function getLocationInfoByIp(){
    $client = @$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    $forward = @$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    $remote = @$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $result = array('country'=>'', 'city'=>'');
    if(filter_var($client, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)){
    $ip = $client;
    }
    elseif(filter_var($forward, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)){
    $ip = $forward;
    }
    else{
    $ip = $remote;
    }
    $ip_data = @json_decode(file_get_contents("http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=".$ip));
    if($ip_data && $ip_data->geoplugin_countryName != null){
    $result['country'] = $ip_data->geoplugin_countryCode;
    $result['city'] = $ip_data->geoplugin_city;
    }
    return $result;
    }
    $location = getLocationInfoByIp();
    $loc= $location['country'];
```

It helps find region code. ex. Azerbaija  AZ, Russian RU

How can I write redirect code with if? 
ex. if location AZ redirects to `mysite.com/az/`
and if location RU redirects to `mysite.com/ru/`
then all other regions should redirect to `mysite.com/en/`

Thanks good-day

Answer (score 1):

Generally it's not a good idea to set the language for users based on the IP alone - what if a tourist visits the country, but doesn't speak the language? And some countries use multiple languages (like Beglium, where people speak Dutch and/or French).

Instead you can check the header set in the browser (detect the language used in the browser, locally), and use that. In addition, it may be a good idea to have a possibility to overrule this, cookies are good for this.

```
$language = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);

switch ($language){
    case "ru":
        header("Location: /ru/");
        exit;
    case "az":
        header("Location: /az/");
        exit;
    case "en": 
    default:
        header("Location: /en/");
        exit;
}
```

You should place checks that only redirects if the two don't match, for example - it's pointless to redirect to `/ru/` if you're already in `/ru/` and the browser-header is set to Russian.

---

The manual states the following about `$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']`:

> 'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'
>   Contents of the Accept-Language: header from the current request, if there is one. Example: 'en'.

- http://php.net/reserved.variables.server
- http://php.net/substr